# Dealing with i/o streams while using Runtime.exec

Tags: java, process, stream

I am trying to run an `scp` command within Java. Here is my code,

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("scp -P" + PORT + " " + FILEPATH + " " + USERNAME + "@" + HOST + ":somefolder/");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("LINE: " + line);
        if (line.contains(USERNAME+"@"+HOST+"'s password:")) {
            bw.write(PASSWORD);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("end of while.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you can see, I do not want to print the password blindly to the `p.getOutputStream()`, which is suggested in almost all similar questions. I want to read the prompt and act accordingly. For example, scp may prompt something like "The authenticity of host 'SOME HOST' can't be established...", which prompts for a yes/no. Or something else that I cannot imagine right now.

The problem with my code is that it never reads a line, although the scp prompts for password, which is seen on the cli. Any suggestion?

**EDIT:**
I changed the code to use ProcessBuilder, with String[] constructor, as Andrew Thompson suggested. Here is the complete code:

```
package scptest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class STest {

    // args => filepath, username, host, port, password
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("scp", "-P", args[3],
                    args[0], args[1] + "@" + args[2] + ":folder/");
            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    p.getOutputStream()));
            String line;
            bw.write(args[4]);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("RETURN: " + p.waitFor());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I quitted checking the prompts of the scp, and sent the password directly to the input stream of Process. This does not work either! I mean, when I execute the jar file in the commad line, I see the prompt "username@host's password:", and it waits for the password. When I hit enter without entering the password, it just re-asks the password without any error message, which means no string is given to the input stream of the `Process`, i.e. My `BufferedWriter` seems doing nothing.

I am compiling my program on a w8 maching with jdk 1.7.0_45, where  I run the program on an Ubuntu Server x64 with jre 1.7.0_51.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784789/call-interactive-perl-script-from-java might help you

Comment: maybe you should use readLine()

Comment: @reto, my code is very similar to the example you provided.

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon, I am already using readLine(), look at the while loop.

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I found that its easier to configure the rsa files and use the -i option in the scp command.

Just use -i  where  is the private key of the HOST machine. You'll also need to add the public key from the machine running the command to the authorized keys file in the HOST machine.

That way he won't prompt you for a password a all. Furthermore if you use the -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null options you'll rarely have anything to worry about (which isn't always a good thing!)

Comment: It was an option in my mind, but I prefer authentication via password. I think it must be 'do'able.